# Fastest way to loop through a SqlDataReader?

Tags: vb.net

I have a select statement that needs to bring in all the labnumbers in the database. But there is about 3000 records and i was wondering to see if there is a faster way to do this? Here is the code.

```
    Try
        Dim labnumber As SqlCommand

        If GenStoredProcs.Location = "CL" Then
            labnumber = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MAT_SAMPLE_TRACKING " &
                    "WHERE LABNO IN " &
                    "(SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_MAIN_GLASS_BEADS " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_MAIN_CYLINDER " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_SHRP_MAIN " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_PAINT_WATERBORNE " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_STOREROOM_BLEND  " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_STONEROOM_INFO  " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_PAINT_EPOXY " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_WINTER_COARSE_MAIN " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_WINTER_FINE_MAIN " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_FINE_AGGREGATE " &
                    "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_REBAR_INFO) " &
                    "ORDER BY LABNO DESC ", modData.MATDB_Connection)
        Else
            'Load Tests table, only labs that have tests
            labnumber = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MAT_SAMPLE_TRACKING " &
                        "WHERE LABNO IN " &
                        "(SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_MAIN_ASPHALT " &
                        "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_MAIN_CONCRETE " &
                        "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_MAIN_BRICKS " &
                        "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_MAIN_GLASS_BEADS " &
                        "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_MAIN_RICE " &
                        "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_MAIN_WET_WASH " &
                        "UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_MAIN_PRECAST) " &
                        "ORDER BY LABNO DESC ", modData.MATDB_Connection)
        End If
        'removed from else condition above should not be needed
        '"UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_SHRP_MAIN " & _
        '"UNION SELECT DISTINCT LABNO FROM MAT_PAINT_WATERBORNE) " & _
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = labnumber.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                If Not IsDBNull(reader("LABNO")) Then
                    cboLabNumber.Items.Add(reader("LABNO"))
                End If
            End While
        End If
        reader.Close()
```

Comment: That HasRows is unnecessary.  If there aren't any rows, the while-loop will just skip over that block.

Comment: Load it into a DataTable and use that as the DataSource and you dont have to loop at all, nor copy the data.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a dataset and just binding to that? Why are you not making the NULL check on the DB? This would be faster than checking every row also.

Comment: Add the condition to remove the null records directly in the query and you don't need to loop

Comment: @LarsTech: well, it doesn't hurt, maybe OP wants to handle that case separately, f.e. log or output that there were no numbers.

Comment: What it is doing is its looping through each record and it will then place each record into a combobox that they can search and select from.

Comment: Yes, we can read the code.  There is no need to do that - data binding will allow data in a datatable to show up in the control